# How can I conditionally Intercept Routes?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I have page `/job` and when user click some job `Link` component on this page will intercepting route to `/job/<jobId>`.

Is there a way to conditional route user to **real page** (render entire page, not intercepting route) without hard refresh the page?

I can't use `Link` component to render entire page due to this note of [Intercepting Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes#:%7E:text=However%2C%20when%20navigating%20to%20the%20photo%20by%20clicking%20a%20shareable%20URL%20or%20by%20refreshing%20the%20page%2C%20the%20entire%20photo%20page%20should%20render%20instead%20of%20the%20modal.%20No%20route%20interception%20should%20occur.).